# Java 9 module and double dispatch in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

On some of my projects, I use the double dispatch mechanism to provide at run time a "view" of my infrastructure module to my domain module ([Strengthening your domain: The double dispatch pattern](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/30/strengthening-your-domain-the-double-dispatch-pattern/)). What I call 'modules' above is simply separate jar files where the dependency from service.jar->domain.jar is enforced at compile time only. Will I be able to have this working on java-9 if I define my service and domain as 'true' java 9 modules?

```
module domain
  L Fee.java
      L Payment recordPayment(double, BalanceCalculator)
  L BalanceCalculator.java
module service
  L BalanceCalculatorImpl.java // implements BalanceCalculator
      L double calculate(Fee fee) //call fee.recordPayment(amount,this)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is possible. Here are some things to consider:

1. The module *domain* needs to [export the package](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#module-declarations) containing `Fee`. Possibly to everyone but at least [to *service*](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#qualified-exports).
2. The module *service* will have to [require *domain*](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#module-declarations) as `BalanceCalculatorImpl` has to [access](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#accessibility) `BalanceCalculator` since it implements it.
3. It looks like clients of *service* need to know about *domain* as well, which is a textbook case for [implied readability](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#implied-readability).
4. In a simple setup either *service* or some third module will have to instantiate `BalanceCalculatorImpl` and pass it to `Fee`, this can not happen in *domain* or it would create a cyclic dependency.
5. A more advanced solution would be [services](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#services), where all code that can access `BalanceCalculator`, even inside *domain*, can get hold of all its implementations.

Taking all of these into account, this is what the two [module declarations](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#module-declarations) might look like:

```
module com.example.domain {
    // likely some requires clauses

    // export packages containing Fee and BalanceCalculator
    exports com.example.domain.fee;
    exports com.example.domain.balance;
}

module com.example.service {
    requires public com.example.domain;
    // likely some more requires clauses

    // expose BalanceCalculatorImpl as a service,
    // which makes it unnecessary to export the containing package
    provides com.example.domain.balance.BalanceCalculator
        with com.example.service.balance.BalanceCalculatorImpl;
}
```

Then every module that likes to use `BalanceCalculator` can declare it in its module declaration with `uses com.example.domain.balance.BalanceCalculator` and get instances of that using [Java's `ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

You can find more practical applications of the module system (particularly for services] in [a demo I created](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jigsaw-advent-calendar/tree/03-services).

(Note: The answer was revised after [this exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771709/java-9-module-and-double-dispatch-in-ddd/39785150?noredirect=1#comment66876154_39785150).)

Comment: Any work around or way to define a kind of runtime `weak` dependency?

Comment: Actually your tree is wrong. In domain, I have an interface let's call it BalanceCalculator and in my service I have the impl of it, call it BalanceCalatorImpl.java.....Am I blocked in that case?

Comment: Can you update your question to include that information - preferably in a diagram. :)